# how to get parameter value when I use htaccess url rewrite with '-' in value

Tags: php, .htaccess

I used htaccess for url rewrite in my gallery page and I used below code in htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/(\w+)/(\w+) gallery_image.php?query=gallery&imgid=$1&slug=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Here slug values should be like `firstname-lastname-imagetitle`;

When I use `$_REQUEST['slug']` to get parameter value, it returns only `firstname`.

Ex: if `slug = 'jum-hague-art-gallery-brown-box'` `$_REQUEST['slug']` returns only `jum`. But I need entire value.

Please help me to find what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minus (-) is word delimeter so `\w` gets only the 1st part of new slug. Write so to take all text after the slash

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/(\w+)/(.+)$ gallery_image.php?query=gallery&imgid=$1&slug=$2 [QSA,L]
```